# Unable to post the data to server, getting error  java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415

Tags: java, curl, http-status-code-415

Iam unable to post the data to the server, getting error as . But it is working fine in curl script.

```
Error reading URL

        java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: https://8.7.177.4/api/domains/amj.nms.mixnetworks.net/subscribers/9001?do_not_disturb=no
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at CurlAuthentication.authenticatePostUrl(CurlAuthentication.java:109)
        at CurlAuthentication.main(CurlAuthentication.java:134)
    Error reading URL
```

Below is the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;


public class CurlAuthentication {

    public void authenticatePostUrl() {

        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                System.out.println("Warning: URL Host: " + urlHostName
                        + " vs. " + session.getPeerHost());
                return true;
            }
        };
        // Now you are telling the JRE to trust any https server.
        // If you know the URL that you are connecting to then this should
        // not be a problem
        try {
            trustAllHttpsCertificates();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Trustall" + e.getStackTrace());
        }
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        try {
            URL url = new URL("www.stackoverflow.com");

            String credentials = "user" + ":" + "password";
            String encoding = Base64Converter.encode(credentials.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            HttpsURLConnection  uc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            uc.setDoInput(true); 
            uc.setDoOutput(true);
            uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoding));
            uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            uc.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(uc.getContentType());
            InputStream content = (InputStream) uc.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    content));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                pw.println(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pw.println("Invalid URL");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pw.println("Error reading URL");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CurlAuthentication au = new CurlAuthentication();
        au.authenticatePostUrl();
    }

    // Just add these two functions in your program

    public static class TempTrustedManager implements
            javax.net.ssl.TrustManager, javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public boolean isServerTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean isClientTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
            return true;
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            return;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            return;
        }
    }

    private static void trustAllHttpsCertificates() throws Exception {

        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains:

        javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] trustAllCerts =

        new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[1];

        javax.net.ssl.TrustManager tm = new TempTrustedManager();

        trustAllCerts[0] = tm;

        javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sc =

        javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);

        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(

        sc.getSocketFactory());

    }


}
```

Do iam doing anything wrong from the above code?
DO i need to use curl script to post the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as [`Error 415`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) is already stating:

> 415 Unsupported Media Type
>
> The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support. For example, the client uploads an image as image/svg+xml, but the server requires that images use a different format.

Without knowing the specifications of what the server is expecting of you to send him, it's hard to tell what you are missing. It though seems as if you only want to receive data from the server and not send him anything.

By setting `uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");` you tell the server that you [hand him over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) some XML data (which you don't) and he probably also wouldn't expect this, so he's giving you that error.

As your sending some urlencoded data in your POST data, try setting this to:

```
uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: You want to send data to the server or do you want to receive something? Which error are you getting now?

Comment: i want to send data to server by post method, above code also describe the same . Now with your suggestion above, iam not getting any exception, but data is not posting to server.

Comment: Are you meaning the authentication data or some other data? Do you have a link to the API documentation?